# State not being set corretly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a model Component in my ReactJs project, where I have a picture being, show and I want to pass the data of the picture, that a user clicked on, it can neither be raw data or a URL.

I have made a handle, that can both delete the picture (if pressed with the Ctrl key), or just open up the modal if clicked normally

```
showModalSpeceficHandler = (event, image) =>{
    let index = this.state.images.indexOf(image)
    if(event.ctrlKey){
        let temp = this.state.images.slice(); //makes a shallow copy of the array
        temp.splice(index, 1); //remove item
        this.setState(prevState => ({ images: temp }));
    }else{
        console.log(image); // logs the data of the clicked image
        this.setState(
            state => ({imageModalData: image}),
            () => this.showModalHandler()
        );
        console.log(this.state.imageModalData) //logs the data of the last added image
    }
}
```

so the issue now is as mentioned in the comments, that the state is not set correctly. I was suspecting that the showModalHandler would change the state but

it simply sets the state, if it should be shown or not:

```
 showModalHandler = () =>{
    this.setState({showModal: !this.state.showModal})
}
```

What is happening, or overwriting the state, since it is not being set correctly

Comment: AFAIK if you want to reference to current state, you should use a callback - `setState((prevState) => ({ showModal: !prevState.showModal }));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is an asynchronous operation.

When your `setState` call needs to refer to the old state you should use the alternative `setState` signature where you pass a function as first argument:

```
setState((state) => ({ showModal: !state.showModal }));
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

This is not technically a *callback*. The callback argument is the *second* `setState` parameter which is rarely used (so, more or less you should never use it).
See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 1):

try to bind your showModalHandler function to this in your constructor like this :

```
constructor(props){
   super(props)
   /* your state*/
   this.showModalHandler = this.showModalHandler.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: I use the arrow function, so binding is not needed, but thank you for your answer!